# Difference between two dates (Android)

Tags: java, android, date-arithmetic

I need to get a time between two dates. Let's say `dateStart = 1470712122173` and `dateStop = 1470712127320`.
The difference between this two dates equals to `5147`
So, according to this I expect to get an answer = 5 seconds but I see `19:00:05`. Where these 19 hours come from?

Code for milliseconds ( = 5147) -> time:

```
private string foo(long dateStart, long dateStop) {
    long diff = dateStop - dateStart;
    DateFormat simple = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(); 
    Date date = new Date(diff); 
    return simple.format(date);
}
```

Thank you for explanation.

Comment: The difference between two time points is not another time point. It's a duration.

Comment: Maybe you are in UTC-5 timezone. You can use Joda lib for time differences or calculate by yourself in seconds, minutes, ..

Comment: @flkes i dont think timezone with +19  exists. I think that its smth with diff value

Comment: Nothing to do with timezones. Just what @LukeLee says: `new Date(diff)` is meaningless. Leave `diff` as a `long`, it's just a number of milliseconds, not a date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the basic concepts right. When you take a difference between two `Date` object, you get the duration between two points in time, trying to view the difference as another time point makes no sense.

Here's a example using the Java 8 time API to get the difference between two points in time (`java.time.Instant`):

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class TimeDifferenceSample {

    static Duration diff(Instant start, Instant end) {
        return Duration.between(start, end);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        long start = 1470712122173L;
        long end = 1470712127320L;

        Duration dur = diff(Instant.ofEpochMilli(start), Instant.ofEpochMilli(end));
        System.out.println(dur.getSeconds() + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5 seconds
```

For Android, I am not an expert, but you can check [The Joda Time Project](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time), which provides similar functions. I also found an [Android verion here](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android).

Answer (score 2):

```
    Date date = new Date(5147);
   //this method has deprecation, just for illustration
    System.out.println(date.getSeconds());

 //in java 8 this works
        LocalDateTime ldate1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1470712122173l), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        LocalDateTime ldate2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1470712127320l), ZoneId.systemDefault());

        System.out.println(Duration.between(ldate1, ldate2).getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`

**Output**

```
0 : 0 : 5
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long dateStart = 1470712122173l, dateStop = 1470712127320l;
        long diff = dateStop - dateStart;

        long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
        long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);

        System.out.println(diffInHours + " : " + diffInMinutes + " : " + diffInSeconds);
    }
}
```

---

When you calculate the difference between two date instances, you're really getting the difference seconds. Let's suppose you get `30 seconds` as difference.

Now if you will convert this `30 seconds` again to `date` instance (in 12 hour) format, then you'll get the answer as `12 hr 00 minutes 30 seconds PM`. So when you calculate the difference between two dates, you shouldn't convert the difference back to the date instance.

Comment: Thank you too, man.